# Passing dynamic URL using Jade and Node.js

Tags: node.js, pug

I am new to Node.js and I am stuck with small issue.

When the user enters Java in textbox and click on submit button It should go to  http://localhost:3000/search/Java

how do we do in Jade ?

Help highly appriciated. Thanks in Advance

```
extends layout
block content
.container

  p(style='white-space:pre;') You are currently logged in as #{user.username}
  br
  a(href="/logout") Logout
  br
  form(role='form', action="/search",method="get", style='max-width: 300px;')
   .form-group
      input.form-control(type='text', name="search", placeholder='enter something')
  button.btn.btn-default(type='submit') Submit



router.get('/search/:id', function(req, res){
Object.find({searchType: req.params.id},function (err, docs){
res.render('search', {search: docs, user : req.user , title : 'Search'});
});
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by including javascript

```
script.
var something = function() {
window.location.href = "search/" +   
document.getElementById('search').value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this?

```
response.writeHead(302, {
  'Location': 'YourNewURL'
  //add other headers here...
});
response.end();
```

Comment: My node.js code is working ok. But i am not able to pass the params dynamically   from textbox

Comment: This works http://localhost:3000/search/Java. But how do i generate one from Jade